# understanding pdo and oop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I learning oop and want to use pdo to execute mysql query. I have a query inside function that I want to execute. When I do this I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on a non-object

What I'am doing wrong?

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function testDuplicate($model) {

    $SQL = "SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE model LIKE '" .$model . "'";
    $result = $conn->exec($SQL);
    if ($result->rows) return false;
    return true;
  }

function testDuplicateCat($cat) {

    $SQL = "SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category WHERE category_id = '" .$cat . "'";
    $result = $conn->exec($SQL);
    if ($result->rows) return false;
    return true;
}

foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $child) {

if(testDuplicate($child->ID)){

...

}

}
```

Comment: You've edited the question so that **the question makes no sense** any longer.  You've added in the `global $conn`, which is part of the answer below.  Please put the question back to it's original form, so it makes sense, and will help future visitors.

Comment: When it comes to PDO i always refer to this guide which is epic https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is raised because the `$conn` variable inside the `testDuplicate` function is not defined inside the scope of the function.

You could do this:

```
  function testDuplicate($model) {
    global $conn;
    ...
  }
```

However it is not advice able to do so, its better to use static variables.

```
function getconn(){
  static $conn;
  if(!isset($conn)){
    $conn = new PDO(...);
  } 

  return $conn;
}

function foobar(){
  $result = getconn()->query($sql);
  while($row = $result->fetch()){
    $ids[] = $row['category_id'];
  }

  return sizeof($ids) > 0 ? $ids : false;
}

if(($list = foobar()) == false){
  echo "products " . var_export($list) . ' are duplicate values';
}
```

Why? Because you cannot simply overwrite the connection variable, even by accident or by using someone elses code. There are better alternatives but this is just a quick and safe example.

Comment: thank you, now I see that i also have other problems with my functions. now I get that error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in

Comment: You're using `exec`, change that to `query` as it returns a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) that you can use to do a [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) on. Then return if the `sizeof($result->fetchALl()) > 0`

Comment: I have to say though, its an inefficient way of doing this. Its better to return the actual result of `fetchAll()` and do something with it. I've updated my answer.